# How to select tag at specific tree hierarchy in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I'm working with XSLT. For one of my requirement I need to catch the tag `<random-text:apple>/<random-text:colour>`

The thing is my XSLT version is 1.0, so I don't have the full regex support.

Let me give a simple example to illustrate the problem statement:

sample.xml:

```
<Fruits>
  <random-text:apple>
    <random-text:colour>RED</random-text:colour>
    <random-text:shape>ROUND</random-text:shape>
  </random-text:apple>
  <random-text:round-fruits>
    <random-text:apple>
      <random-text:colour>RED</random-text:colour>
    </random-text:apple>
  </random-text:round-fruits>
</Fruits>
```

So in the sample.xml, I want to catch `<random-text:apple>/<random-text:colour>` tag but I want to avoid the same tag in other tree hierarchy like `<random-text:round-fruits>/<random-text:apple>/<random-text:colour>`

I tried something like this: `"/*[contains(name(), 'apple')]/*[contains(name(), 'colour')]"` but as you can suspect, it is catching the /apple/colour element in all the tree hierarchy levels.

So, I want to ask:

1. Is it possible to apply wildcards like */apple/colour to get the desired behaviour in XSL 1.0?
2. If yes, please suggest

UPDATE:
Sorry, I forgot to mention earlier that the random-text is properly defined but I have to do it for many such xml files, so I want something like: `<any-namespace:apple>/<any-namespace:colour>` element

Comment: XPath works on XML with namespaces so for your sample with prefixes we need to see any namespace declarations for the prefixes used.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I updated the question a bit, please see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I am missing the point here, because this seems like a trivial problem. The expression:

```
/Fruits/random-text:apple/random-text:colour
```

will select the `random-text:colour` element in the `random-text:apple` branch, and exclude the other `random-text:colour` element in the `random-text:round-fruits` branch.

This is assuming your XML has a proper namespace declaration for the `random-text` prefix and that this declaration is repeated in your stylesheet.

Demo: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/asoTKq

---

***-- added --***

> I have to do it for many such xml files, so I want something like: any-namespace:apple/any-namespace:colour element

That is not a healthy situation. Namespaces are part of the XML schema - and a stylesheet should be written for a specific schema.

Still, you could do:

```
/Fruits/*[local-name()='apple']/*[local-name()='colour']
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention in the question, so the random-text is properly defined but I have to do it for many such xml files with different namespaces, so I want something like: <any-namespace:apple>/<any-namespace:colour> element

Comment: See the addition to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems local-name( ) is not supported in version 1.0?

Comment: Sure it is: https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#section-Node-Set-Functions

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Thanks!